# Why can't I cast this class to an interface?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have a generic interface:

```
public interface IAaa<T> where T : ParentClass {
List<T> MyList {get;}
}
```

I have a child class 'ChildClass' that inherits from 'ParentClass' and implements the above interface:

```
public class ChildClass : ParentClass, IAaa<AnotherChildClassThatInheritsFromParentClass>.
```

In another class I am trying to cast it (edited for context):

```
ParentClass pClass = (ParentClass) new ChildClass();
IAaa<ParentClass> iaaa = (IAaa<ParentClass>) pClass;
```

However the above is giving me an "Cannot cast from source to destination type" error at runtime.
I suspect this is because ParentClass does not implement the IAaa interface. Am I correct? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Hard to say without a more complete code example. But it _looks_ like you are trying to use your `IAaa<T>` interface variantly. If so, that is only possible if the interface actually _is_ variant, and you declare it that way. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233059(v=vs.110).aspx for more details.

Comment: @PeterDuniho seems like what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes, that page does include that example. Can you elaborate on why you are quoting that here?

Comment: Show your interface declaration. That matters if you need covariant interface.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I edited my question. I hope it helps.

Comment: I've marked your question as duplicate. Follow that link to learn more. Basically you need a covariant interface which you can declare it like this `public interface IAaa<out T> where T : ParentClass 
{
 IEnumerable<T> MyList {get;}
}`

Comment: Thanks! Sorry it came to have been already asked.

Comment: The above doesn't work. Once I find a fix I'll post it here.